# How to capture the GraphQL error message in Relay?

Tags: graphql, relay, graphene-python, relaymodern

On my server, my implementation of GraphQL is using Flask, Graphene, and SQLAlchemy. Ideally I would like to be able to simply manipulate the headers and return a 401 error response, but GraphQL returns everything as 200.

Using flask.abort(401) however I am at least able to obtain this response:

```
...
"errors": [
  {
    "message": "401 Unauthorized: The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested.  You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.",
    "locations": [
      {
      "line": 11,
      "column": 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
...
```

I see this as a compromise that I can work with at this point in time. However; because nothing can just be that simple... I am not sure as to how I can grab this error message. I've read that there might an issue with the `QueryRenderer` itself that swallows these GraphQL errors but I can manage to intercept them in the `Network` object in the `Environment`... that essentially looks something like this.

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: {…}}
  __proto__: Promise[
    [PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
    [[PromiseValue]]: Object
      data: {viewer: {…}}
      errors: Array(4)
        0: {locations: Array(1), message: "401 Unauthorized: The server could not verify that…nderstand how to supply the credentials required."}
        1: {locations: Array(1), message: "401 Unauthorized: The server could not verify that…nderstand how to supply the credentials required."}
        2: {locations: Array(1), message: "401 Unauthorized: The server could not verify that…nderstand how to supply the credentials required."}
        3: {locations: Array(1), message: "401 Unauthorized: The server could not verify that…nderstand how to supply the credentials required."}
      length: 4
      __proto__: Array(0)
    __proto__:Object
```

I don't really feel like handling this error at the Network layer of my Environment would be the proper way to manage this. The QueryRenderer seems to make the most sense... I have set it up essentially as the single source of truth.

I am using Relay Modern by the way if that wasn't obvious. So more likely than not any solutions based around Relay Classic will not apply.

Edit: Error message aside, my motivation for this was proper handling of JWT tokens. I think the solution I am looking for isn't related to handling these error responses but rather expanding my understanding of JWT.

I didn't realize that my client would easily be able to decode the JWT using a package such as the `jwt-decode` which then gives me access to expiration information... which ultimately I foresee leading me to some form of middleware implementation that would assess the amount of time remaining on the JWT and if a refresh is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle server errros in the `onCompleted` callback: https://github.com/facebook/relay/pull/1938/files

Comment: How to use this `onCompleted`callback ? Is it available on Relay Modern ? Is it available on queries as well ?

Comment: It's available on Relay Modern. I can't describe the usage more than the document. It's for mutations. That's the point I was missing when I answered the question.

Comment: Can also use the onError callback?

Answer (score 2):

In `environment.js`, modify `fetch` function such that if `errors` array exists in JSON response, you will throw it as a new custom error. This thrown error will get transmitted to `QueryRenderer` where it will be available as `error` prop. Handle it there, by showing error related UI if an error is present.

See this comment on GitHub for detailed explanation:
https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1913#issuecomment-470541691

Answer (score 1):

I hope I am understanding your question correctly, bit your QueryRenderer should have an error object that conains the error
https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/query-renderer.html

```
render={({error, props}) => {
if (error) {
  return <div>{error.message}</div>;
} else if (props) {
  return <div>{props.page.name} is great!</div>;
}
return <div>Loading</div>;
```

Comment: These errors assume that the application has not failed. Turns out I don't need to deal with the error messages after all, but FYI it refers to the Environmental errors at the network level which typically result in critical failures of the application. I no longer have the snippet laying around to demonstrate unfortunately.

Comment: ok that's interesting so the QueryRender error only fires in some instances and some errors from the network layer don't propagate to QueryRenderer? That's interesting. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The `QueryRenderer` error is rendered only if GraphQL payload data is null, otherwise it will swallows it....